# Leitura em arquivo JSON gerando erro

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

Estou tentando fazer uma leitura no JSON, e resultar oque eu desejo em uma div mas meu console esta retornado o seguinte erro,

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load
```

Arquivo JSON:

```
{"content":{"nome":"Josimara","pais":"brasil"}}
```

HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {

        $.get("arquivo/json", {  },
        function(data){
        $("#nome").html(data.nome);
        }, "json");

    });

</script>

<div id="nome"></div>
```

Oque pode ser esse erro?

Comment: Entäo esse erro é porque o URL não tem CORS ativo, ou seja, bloqueia pedidos externos. Podes fazer esse ajax no servidor?

Comment: @Sergio não posso fazer no servidor é uma API externa que eu pego as informações, qual seria a solução melhor pra esse caso?

Comment: Essa API suporta JSONP?

Comment: @Josimara, voce poderia nos dizer qual a `API`? a questão é, ela provavelmente está bloqueando o acesso, por não ter o `CORS` ativo (como o sergio falou), e o `JSONP`  seria uma alternativa para "contornar" o problema

Comment: @Josimara se puder passar o link, ajudaria

Comment: @RafaelAugusto Posso sim claro, https://help.trustedcompany.com/hc/pt-br/articles/115000861763-API-Dados-de-classifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-da-loja e https://help.trustedcompany.com/hc/pt-br/articles/213341086-Melhore-seu-CTR-em-resultados-org%C3%A2nicos-usando-Rich-Snippets

Comment: @Josimara AS suas Chave estão certas? isso pode estar influenciando em problema com `CORS`

Comment: Sim sim @RafaelAugusto corretas, porque se não não gera o json

Comment: @RafaelAugusto a empresa da API esta fazendo uma verificação no servidor deles pra ver se o CORS esta habilitado, vamos aguardar :)

Comment: @Josimara Quando fizerem, nos diga como foi ;)

Answer (score 1):

O Problema é `CORS`, ao testar o codigo a baixo, recebi o seguinte erro.
`Failed to load https://trustedcompany.com/api/v1/company/bbbaterias.com.br?key=f157aee72a787417c20a71ac21708ee8-1b06b0bab68ccc183f78742e3bb8f852: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8081' is therefore not allowed access.`

```js
$.ajax({
 type: 'GET',
 url: 'https://trustedcompany.com/api/v1/company/bbbaterias.com.br?key=f157aee72a787417c20a71ac21708ee8-1b06b0bab68ccc183f78742e3bb8f852',
 dataType: 'json',
 cache: false,
 success: function(data){
           $('#app').html(data)
    console.log(data)
 }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

O que quer dizer que você não tem "permissão" para acessar o servidor, fiz o teste com `jsonp` e parece que tambem não funcionou, se caso a `documentação` não tiver algo sobre isso, você não conseguira.